# How To Parse(DeSerialise) Json String in java using Gson Library

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to parse the following JSON in Java using Gson Library. Can anyone help me as I am new to JSON?

```
alarmEvent = {
  "version" : "1.0" 
  "type" : "ALARM", 
  "nodeId" : "",
  "timeStamp" : "", 
  "params" : {
    "paramId" : "",
    "alarmType" :  "", 
    "category" : "", 
    "source" : "", 
    "parameter": "", 
    "alarm" : "", 
    "alias" : "", 
    "duration" : "" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you at least considered reading the documentation of Gson? https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide Why do you think documentation is being written?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `AlarmEvent` class, containing a member for each field you expect to see in the JSON object. For example:

```
class AlarmEvent {
    private String version;
    private String type;
    ....
}
```

Then, you can instantiate an object of this type as follows:

```
AlarmEvent a = new Gson().fromJson(json, AlarmEvent.class);
```

You can now access the fields directly as `a.version`, `a.type`, etc.

Comment: I tried this but i am getting the values of first object but  i need to get all objects values hierarchically

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
```